# Eclipse - Could not publish server configuration for Tomcat8.0 server at localhost

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, servlets

I have created some example web service methods and trying to publish in my localhost with Tomcat v8.0. I use Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers with Mars version 4.5.0.
  I configured the server Tomcat v8.0. I got the configured server in Eclipe's Servers list. I Start the server. But Eclipse prompts saying

```
 Publishing to tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost..." has encountered a problem.
```

And the error details shows that Multiple context have a path for `/HelloWorldServlet` and `/com.vogeila.jersy.first`. These are the servlet projects I created in my workspace.

You can refer this screen shot:
[image]

I followed this answer.

["Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start" without stack trace while it works in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244233/server-tomcat-v7-0-server-at-localhost-failed-to-start)

But It didn't work for my case.
 Share your ideas.

Answer (score 18):

The prompted message helped me. The `Server.xml` file under `Servers` has multiple entries of `<Context>` tag. I deleted everything by leaving only one entry. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Delete Existing tomcat server...
Then add new server.. its work for me