# Getting error when calling a servlet

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

I am new to servlet.I am trying to call a Servlet to verify the username and password.
But when executed,tomcat gives the error "The requested resource is not available"

Following is the code.

RequestServlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RequestServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/RequestServlet")
public class RequestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    PrintWriter out;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */

    public void service(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        ((ServletResponse) res).setContentType("text/html");
        out=((ServletResponse) res).getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println(req.getMethod());

    String name=req.getParameter("name");
        String pass=req.getParameter("pass");
        if(name.equals("asad")&&pass.equals("123"))
            out.println("user is valid");
        else
            out.println("not valid");
        out.println("</body></html>");  
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Learnserv</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RequestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>RequestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet> 

   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RequestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/RequestServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>asd.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

asd.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/RequestServlet"   method="GET">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="password" name="pass">
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Is your Servlet class really in default package?

Comment: Yes,its in src folder.

Comment: Next question: what is Web application context name? You are trying to access by absolute path <form action="/RequestServlet" .. /> and maybe that's why? Did you try to access your Servlet using path: localhost:8080/<webappname>/RequestServlet ?

Comment: No,this is not working.

Comment: clean , build and deploy your application again, then try *localhost:<port>/<webappname>/RequestServlet* again

Comment: @javy, i already tried it,it also gives error "The webpage cannot be displayed"

Comment: Something has changed? Firstly, there was "The requested resource is not available" and now it's "The webpage cannot be displayed" ?

Comment: After cleaning and reopening the application,i am getting another error related to server "Server Apache Tomcat v7.0 (2) at localhost failed to start."

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13244233/4290096) for tomcat failed to start issue.

Comment: Where do i find "workspace-directory" because someone has answered to go to this location <workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `<form action="/RequestServlet"   method="GET">`
to `<form action="RequestServlet"   method="post">` I think `/RequestServlet` is replaced by `localhost:port/RequestServlet` but need `localhost:port/context/RequestServlet` (if do not deploy at webapps/ROOT for Tomcat)

Also, if use `@WebServlet("/RequestServlet")` then to do the same in `web.xml` is  dublicate. Or annotation or web.xml.

And place `PrintWriter out` inside `service` to be thread safe.