# Why is my Tomcat server 7 not working in Eclipse luna?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7, eclipse-luna

It is working fine with Eclipse indigo but not with luna.
 Its giving error

> "Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start"

as a dialog box.do help me.

Comment: Could you please post the complete error log,

Comment: that is the only message I am getting as Dialog box.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244233/server-tomcat-v7-0-server-at-localhost-failed-to-start-without-stack-trace-whi) - check this, you might be facing the same issue then.